# iOS: perform performSelector using nsstring : performSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown

Tags: ios, objective-c, performselector

I'm trying to perform performSelector selecting methods from nsarray but I'm getting this error:

performSelector may cause a leak beacause its selector is unknown

Here is my code:

```
-(void)exceudeMethods
{
    NSArray *methods = @[@"methodOne",@"methodTwo"];

    for (int i =0 ; i < methods.count; i++)
    {
       [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:",methods[i]])];

    }

}
```

if I replace any of you know how can I fix this so I can execute all the methods in the nsarray?

Comment: `selector` is unknown means there is no method with the name you are providing... check once for its correct name.

Comment: show your method definition

Comment: Why `stringWithFormat`???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

strange that the warning is removed if you replace the line with

```
    [self  performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(methods[i]) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];
```

seems to work.